# How to boost up Magento website after 1.6?

Tags: performance, magento

I've used Magento a lot since 1.3. And Magento team had improved the performances of it a lot but now it is "after 1.6" era. But the speed of Magento is still not very good.

There're a lot of post discussing how to improve it, for example:

1. gzip compression
2. minify HTML, CSS, JSS (remove all
   unneccessary white space)
3. Optimise your images
4. Disable any unused modules 
   5.Combine external CSS/JS into one file
5. Cachefiles that can be cached
6. Etc.

However, can someone shad some light on the bottle neck of the slow speed of Magento from a programming framework level? And how much can we improve for that?

It would be very intersting to modify something in Magento so as to boost it up. Isn't it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tweaking magento for performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216743/tweaking-magento-for-performance)

Answer (score 4):

Your hosting platform can have a huge effect! I found extreme speed improvement using nginx and php-fpm. We also implemented a REST database server. All this on a Amazon EC2 php-fpm ubuntu instance.

Comment: thanks Chris. Is there any comparison between the performance of Apache and Nginx?

Comment: Sonam please see @Francesco's answer below. In it, someone actually quantifies what I witnessed and "felt".

Answer (score 2):

Here a guide with benchmark:
http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/optimizing-magento-performance/

I found this guide about performance and Magento, It looks very well done:
http://mage-page.net/2012/08/tips-tricks-to-speed-up-magentp/

Answer (score 0):

In magento there are various js files involving a lot of files, Fooman Speedster extension by Fooman is very good and also very nice extension to speed up the magento site. Its availble on connect and really has effects on magento store.