# Slow Magento Enterprise

Tags: magento

We are using Magento Enterprise Edition on Nginx and FPC. Dedicated servers with ample ram and CPU. Everything runs fine with 60-70 visitors. However during high traffic like over 200 active visitors, we starts to have problem. During peak traffic our CPU is still under 10% and with 40% free memory. We have a dedicated App and DB server.

What could be wrong? Could this be a network issue? What are the chances that there is a problem with App server or the code base is not optimized given the fact that CPU is under 10% with ample ram.

Steve

Edit:

I am running a 32 core App server with 64GB of RAM. Have Nginx with PHP-FPM and FASTCGI. Upon checking the logs I found that that PHP-FPM has following errors during peak Hours:

[WARNING] [pool www] child 26196, script '/var/www/magento/index.php' execution timed out (600.011284 sec), terminating

I have 32 Workers process along with worker_connections  1024;

CDN is already setup and network is set to use 1G connection.

Comment: Can you profile your MYSQL load as Magento has an absolute pig of a database structure? Under heavy load it could easily be your bottleneck.

Comment: MySQL server CPU is under 2%. Is there a shell command for this?

Comment: The CPU load may be small, but the disk IO could be enormous. I'm sorry, but I'm not a linux admin so I can't help you with the command.

Comment: We are using SSD on RAID 10. Here is the IO Total DISK READ: 0.00 B/s | Total DISK WRITE: 53.85 K/s

Comment: Total: 189 (kernel 255)
TCP:   60 (estab 45, closed 2, orphaned 0, synrecv 0, timewait 2/0), ports 11

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
*         255       -         -
RAW       0         0         0
UDP       11        6         5
TCP       58        55        3
INET      69        61        8
FRAG      0         0         0

Comment: In order to actually get responses you need to post a detailed schema of your achitecture(servers, specs, etc)/setup and info about services running on each machine, caching used, data about what happens when the load is increasing (mysql is overloaded, the webservers have issues?). Else you will just get answers from cowboys that have no clue. Eg: Paul Smith website is running on nginx/fpc and handles heavy load very well. *It's not a networking issue, it's Magento and the setup*.

Comment: sound stupid but what about bandwidth ?

Comment: just want to add this question is a kind of off-topic

Comment: Take a look at Vinai's response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216743/tweaking-magento-for-performance

Comment: Thanks. Vinai's post is really helpful.