# How to optimize Magento for increased user load

Tags: php, performance, apache, .htaccess, magento

How can I configure Magento so that:

1) it can handle 10000 customers at a time

2) it can tolerate sudden increase in load

I searched Google but most of articles are explaining to improve Magento load time.

Where should I set the cookies and session expiration time?

I want to achieve this by modifying `.htaccess` ,`php.ini` and Magento admin panel setting.

Other ways are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done extensive testing on this and have found the single biggest thing to do to improve performance is the following.
(all the following links can be found at http://www.magentocommerce.com/)

- Make sure Magento Caching is enabled (easy to overlook when you have 
  it turned off while developing)
- Use some sort of full page caching such as
  magento-connect/zoom-full-page-cache-1742.html
- Use a CDN such as MaxCDN or AWS Cloudfront (using
  magento-connect/6274.html makes this pretty easy)

The above make the big improvements. If you need more improvements installing varnish really does the biggest but can be a pain to use since it is normally setup to take over port 80. This makes managing and developing your site later a bit of a pain as you will generally need to disable it or have it bypass varnish to do any major development work.

- Install varnish - magento-connect/pagecache-powered-by-varnish.html
  or magento-connect/2984.html
- Make sure you have APC and Memcached installed
- Make sure you have gzip compression turned on.

Advance performance method (these are helpful if using AWS and you want to use multiple servers in different zones)

- Install varnish on it's own server and direct the web-server port to
  your Magento server. This reduces the number of hits your web-server
  sees.
- Install your magento database on it's own server. Magento has funny resource requirements memory and cpu wise. What may be good for Magento might not be as good for the web server etc or database. Splitting your database off should be fine if you are one the same local net (i.e. AWS same region). This method allows you to use multiple web servers.
- Use a AWS with elastic IP and place webservers in different zones and multiple web servers with a single database server. Use multiple varnish servers infront of the web servers.

Some additional notes:
APC, Memcache, php, using ngix will only provide about a 10% improvement vs just using Magento Cache, full page cache and Varnish. Also before testing make sure you test your server setup using a stock magento install with dummy data. This will help you set a baseline performance to see if hardware changes or need or to identify if a module or other plugin might be causing big performance hits. Sites like loadimpact.com can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to `php.ini` then I am going to take a wild guess and assume you also have access to your database configuration files (`my.conf`).

In case you are using MySQL adjusting the `query_cache_size` parameter can have a tremendous positive effect on Magento performance because its constantly polling a large amount of the same data that gets reused. The exact amount of memory you'll use depends entirely on your needs so you will have to adjust it accordingly.

Comment: I have access to both php.ini and my.conf. What should I change there?

Comment: Just look for `query_cache_size` in the `[mysqld]` section (if its not there add it) and change the parameter value to something that suits your needs. Typically a value between `32M` and `64M` is enough (`query_cache_size=64M`) but if your hardware allows it feel free to experiment with higher values. Though it would be required only with an extremely high number of products/requests.

Answer (score 1):

1. FPC is the most important point that should be applied.This will reduce your Mysql load considerably.
2. Solr for search is the second thing that should be done.
3. Make sure your code is to Magento standards so that it effectively uses magento cache and FPC.

Above three will result in Max optimization.
Look here : [Tweaking magento for performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216743/tweaking-magento-for-performance/15458875#15458875) for lots of additional points.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to optimize Magento. Some of the configuration are from Magento admin panel it self.

1. Go to: System->Configuration->CATALOG/Catalog->Frontend

   Use Flat Catalog Category: Yes

   Use Flat Catalog Product : Yes
2. Go to: System->Configuration->ADVANCED/Developer: Merge javascript and CSS
3. Install memcache on you server

Some of the Helping links:

http://magento2x.com/speed-up-magento/

http://support.metacdn.com/entries/25027521-Slow-Magento-Speed-up-Magento-with-our-Magento-Optimization-guide

Also you can go for Google and find some more terrific configuration for server.

Comment: I am concerned about increased user traffic. Site should not go slow or down on sudden load increase

Comment: If you are not using memcache, then install it and configure. you can decrease each page load time by at-least 50%. It is my personal experience.

Comment: If I revert back again from Flat Catalog Category and Flat Catalog Product, will this affect adversely to the site?

Comment: No, only you need to reindex.

Comment: i wonder how flat catalog will help you with 10k online and increased server load??? irrelevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

one simple way is to install and config APC

[APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)

```
# in php.ini:
extension=apc.so

[apc]
apc.enabled = 1
apc.cache_by_default = On
apc.shm_segments = 1
apc.shm_size = 128M    ; memory size when using as nosql
apc.ttl = 60
apc.user_ttl = 7200
apc.gc_ttl = 600
apc.num_files_hint = 0
apc.write_lock = On
;apc.stat = 0    ; enable detecting file stat, reload if changed
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to red this "White Paper: Optimizing Magento for Peak Performance"

This white paper documents the exceptional performance that can be achieved by properly optimizing and configuring Magento Enterprise Edition. The resulting optimization not only can contribute to higher conversion rates and support for greater numbers of customers and orders per day, it can also lead to improved hardware efficiency and overall cost savings.

https://info.magento.com/Optimizing_Magento_for_Peak_Performance.html