# What Causing Slowdown Magento Speed

Tags: php, magento

Right now i am upgrading a Magento store (Having 1.5GB database after deleting logs) from 1.6 to 1.8. I have configured the project on my local development environment but i have found that the Magento instance is running very slow (15 min to display a single page)

I have started debugging the code and found that below code in app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Vaelow rien\Front.php

```
while (!$request->isDispatched() && $i++<100) {
        foreach ($this->_routers as $router) {
            if ($router->match($this->getRequest())) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

is taking too long time to execute. There was Approx 90 extension were install and i have removed most of them. Now only 15-20. Is there any way to identity and improve it ?

Comment: `break 2` instead of `break`?

Comment: That looks like a complete hack job on Magento's part. Waiting for dispatch with a "timeout" count to make their hack not infinite loop.

Comment: @MrYellow - No, it's there to break out of infinite loops if there are no routers matching the request. NOT a timing loop waiting for response. It's Magento, he's got other severe issues.

Answer (score 0):

There are few Magento configuration.
There is a need of a good hardware with Apache properly configured to handle.

You first need to make sure your computer where you have installed is good enough to handle Magento with that big data base.

Once done you need to look at configuration points:
1. Cache should be on and is writable.
2. Disbale unwanted modules.
3. Switch on profiler to make our which part of code is consuming lot of time.
4. Use of flat catalog.
5. Run indexing to make sure flat table is in use.

Also : [Tweaking magento for performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216743/tweaking-magento-for-performance/15458875#15458875) has lots of speed related pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Few days ago my site also faces the same Problem. This solved my problem, Check your cache and indexing, these shod be enable.

To enable caches : Go to admin panel > system > Cache management
To enable Index : Go to admin panel > system > Index management

Also remove the unwanted script running on the sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the below steps for Magento Optimization:

1. High Performance Dedicated Server. Ex: Amazon EC2 cloud
2. Swap Apache for NGINX
3. Minimize Javascript use
4. Minify and Compressed CSS files
5. ‘Combine CSS’ seeks to reduce the number of HTTP requests made by a
   browser
6. Optimize images
7. Use lazyload for images
8. Specify Image dimensions
9. Combine images into CSS sprites
10. Use a Content Delivery Network (CDN) for delivering static files
     like JS, CSS and Images to offload your server
11. Disable modules/extension which are not required
12. Enable all Magento Caches
13. Use a Full Page Cache / Varnish Cache / Memcache / RedisCache
14. Don’t use layered navigation if you don’t really need it, it needs
     a lot of resources
15. Enable Compilation
16. Limit the number of products on a product overview page.
17. Set only those attribute frontend properties to ‘Yes’ that you’re
     actually going to use. Set all other to ‘No’.
18. Don’t use in quick search, advanced search compare, etc. : Catalog
     -> Attributes -> Manage Atributes -> Frontend Properties.
19. Install Google Page Speed Module
20. Minimize redirects – Minimizing HTTP redirects from one URL to
     another cuts out wait time for users.
21. Prefer asynchronous resources – Fetching resources asynchronously
     prevents those resources from blocking the page load.