# how to make magento search functionality faster?

Tags: mysql, ajax, magento, search, query-optimization

I have developed a magento website but searching the product catalogue is very slow. How can I improve the searching speed?

Here is my website.

http://kawasakiretail.com/

Comment: How many products are in your catalog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is your flat catalog turned on or not.If not switch it on.
2. Use Solr for search you might need to purchase some Solr bridge extension.
3. Make sure you have optimized Magento : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216743/tweaking-magento-for-performance/15458875#15458875  this link has lots of magento speed optimization tips.